# Convert number to fax format.

Tags: number

I want to display the number in fax format. If the user enter the number as 12345678910 it need to be formated as (1234)(567)(8910) can it be possible through formula field without writing trigger. If possible please help me how can we achieve it through formula field or please suggest me any other best way to achieve it.

Comment: Will the user always enter the number in the same format, or do you need to check for different ways of typing the number in?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by Formula field and Workflow (Field Update rule). You can do something like this:

```
IF(
    LEN(Phone__c )==10, 
      '('+LEFT( Phone__c , 4)+')('+ MID(Phone__c, 5, 7)+')('+   RIGHT(Phone__c, 4)+')',
    'Format Invalid'
   );
```

You can use nested formula `IF` condition to support various length numbers.

Create a workflow rule and set its run criteria "formula evaluate to true" write `true` in formula text box.

**Note:-** I have not tested it. You may need to change some number used to cut digits. Except this it will work.

Read about formulas what they do:

> - LEFT
> - RIGHT
> - MID